# Face dataset organized by folder

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, image-recognition

I'm looking for a quite little/medium dataset (from 50MB to 500MB) that contains photos of famous people organized by folder.

The tree structure have to bee something like this:

```
├── bfegan
      └── ...
├── chris
      └── ...
├── dhawley
      └── ...
├── graeme
      └──...
├── heather
      └──...
```

Do you know some dataset that have this tree structure?

I want to understand how my very basic neural network is able to detect face in a 'real-world' situation.

https://github.com/alessiosavi/PyRecognizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a dataset the meet the specification here:

https://www.kaggle.com/atulanandjha/lfwpeople/data#lfw-funneled.tgz

Some people in this dataset have only very few image.

We can create a new one dataset using the following bash command, in order to exctract only the people that contains more than 5 images:

```
# Extract only the people that have more than 5 photos (-gt 5)
for i in $(ls); do a=$(ls $i |wc -l); if [ "$a" -gt 5 ]; then echo $i ; fi ; done > people_ok
# Create a directory for store the images
mkdir -p /tmp/faces
# Copy the filtered directory in the new one
for i in $(cat people_ok  | xargs echo -n) ; do cp -r $i /tmp/faces/ ; done
```